# Javascript variable inside qoute (double inside single qoute)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to use a variable in nodejs. It giving me errors whatever I try. 
How can I use a variable in this string

```
 let txt= 'some unknown texts'
 "MATCH (productName) AGAINST ('txt')"
```

Here I need to replace txt.

**Note: I cannot use ``` `` ```**

**Edit**
Here is the query I am using

```
await Product.query().whereRaw("MATCH (productName) AGAINST ('txt')").select('productName')
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the whole SQL query? That will help everyone in understanding the exact problem :)

Comment: Ok updated the answer after going through some of my code, should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ES6 you need to do the following to use a var in string

```
`MATCH (productName) AGAINST ${txt}`
```

IF you cannot use **``**

Just go for the old way with string concatanation,

```
"MATCH (productName) AGAINST '" +txt + "'"
```

Comment: sorry, I cannot use it as it will ruin the sql main statements. I tried it at the very first and got sql errors.

Comment: Just thought you just needed the string, I'll update the answer.

Comment: You should explain the whole scenario in the question.